# Why can't transplant the command from bash into awk?

Tags: bash, awk, tr

```
x="qwerty"
x=$(echo $x | tr [a-z] [A-Z]);
echo $x
QWERTY
```

I want to transplant it into awk.
1 to save as format.awk

```
#! /usr/bin/awk
{
x=$(echo -n $0 | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
print $x 
}
```

2  awk -f format.awk file

```
awk: format.awk: line 3: syntax error at or near tr
```

Why and how to fix it?

It is easy to translate whole file with **cat file |tr [a-z] [A-Z]**,there are many other works to do in awk,so it is necessary to translate lines one by one in awk,other task ommited.

Comment: awk is not a shell, it's a programming language. You could do that with awk but that is not awk's syntax. If you want that text to upper, use `toupper()`: `echo qwerty|awk '{print toupper($0)}'`.

Comment: Btw, if you're using Bash 4.0 or above, you could just: `echo ${x^^}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `tr` like this:

You can do something like this:

```
awk '{print | "tr \"[a-z]\" \"[A-Z]\""}' file
```

Or better do it entirely in `awk` as:

```
awk '{line = toupper($0); print line}' file
```

Comment: even `awk '{print toupper($0)}'` file

Comment: Yes I know. I set a variable because OP seems to be doing much more that just `toupper`